# Angular Partials -- Calling From Controller Possible?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Controller that is grabbing data via a Factory.  That Factory is attached to an API that is being served up by Laravel 5.

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, AccountService) {

    $scope.accounts = [];

    $scope.loadAccounts = function () {
        AccountService.getData('account', 'active').then(function (data) {
                $scope.accounts = data;
            }
        );
    };

    $scope.loadAccounts();
}

controllersModule.controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);
```

What I want this controller to do is call a partial view and feed the `$scope.accounts` into that partial view.

Here is what my overarching HTML file looks like that should load in the partial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <!--title('{{title}}')-->
    <meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/handheld.css" media="screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1024px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:767px)">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header id="header">
        <div class="page clearfix">
          <div class="top">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">khaccsupport</a></li>
              <li><a href="">khaccsupport</a></li>
              <li><a href="">shane@khaccounts.net</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><a href="/" class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png"></a>
          <section class="secondary-header">
            <nav class="navigation">
              <ul>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts/" class="top-link">Buy WoW Accounts</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="sell-wow-accounts/" class="top-link">Sell WoW Accounts</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="customer-reviews-feedback" class="top-link">Reviews / Feedback</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="buy-sell-wow-accounts-faq" class="top-link">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </section>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="fb-frame">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkhaccounts&amp;amp;width=450&amp;amp;height=35&amp;amp;colorscheme=light&amp;amp;layout=standard&amp;amp;action=like&amp;amp;show_faces=false&amp;amp;send=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="page">
          <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-wrapper index-page">
        <footer id="footer">
          <div class="page">
            <div class="footer-content clearfix">
              <div class="links-wrapper clearfix">
                <section class="footer-links nav">
                  <h4>Navigation</h4>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts">Buy High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="/sell-wow-accounts">Sell High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="/">High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts For Sale</a><br><a href="/customer-reviews-feedback">KHAccounts.net Customer Reviews & Feedback</a><br><a href="/buy-sell-wow-accounts-faq">KHAccounts.net Buy & Sell WoW Accounts FAQ</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <div class="secondary-footer"><a href="" class="footer-logo"><img src="../images/footer-logo.png"></a><span class="copyright">©2015 Knucklehead Accounts -- All Rights Reserved.</span></div>
                  </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="footer-links reference">
                  <h4>Referral Links</h4>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.maskedarmory.com">Anonymous WoW Armory Profiles</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com">Trade WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com/buy-sell-trade-mmorpg/">MMO Game Account Trading</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com/buy-sell-trade-world-warcraft-wow/">WoW Trading Forum</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.arenarating.com/category/rbg-rating-boost/world-of-warcraft/">RBG Rating Boost</a><br><a href="https://www.arenarating.com/category/arena-boost-3v3/world-of-warcraft/">Arena Rating Boost</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com">TwinkInfo.com</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com/forums">TwinkInfo.com Forums</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com/forums/f200/">Twinking Guides</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I don't want to put a controller name on the div because I trying to reuse this wrapper for every page.  The only thing that should change is the content in the ui-view when the user navigates to a new page or what not.

I don't know if all of this is possible, but I thought I would give it a shot.

Please let me know if you have any questions as I am sure that I didn't explain all of this correctly...

Comment: Controller is about scope data, so what do you mean "What I want this controller to do is call a partial view and feed the $scope.accounts into that partial view."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ng-include directive if you plan to include partials. Check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/637PgqOS3AHELrKzJh4C) for reference.

```
<div ng-include="'HomePartial.html'"></div>
```

Will contain your home HTML markup. Inside this partial you will need to put the controller HomeCtrl.

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <h1>Home Partial</h1>
</div>
```

This allows you to keep your outer HTML markup as generic as possible and divide and conquer using partials. You can change the ng-include at runtime as needed (or better yet, using routes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-route to handle the controller association with the views. You don't need to specify the controller in the route itself.

```
<div class="container">
<h1>ng-route</h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href='#view1'>View 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#view2'>View 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script type=text/ng-template id=partial/view1.html>
  <h3>View1</h3>
  <div>{{data}}</div>
</script>

<script type=text/ng-template id=partial/view2.html>
  <h3>View2</h3>
  <div>{{data}}</div>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('app', ['myModule', 'ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partial/view1.html', controller: 'ctrl'})
    .when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partial/view2.html', controller: 'ctrl2'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: 'view1'})
});

angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.data = 'Some data for view1';
})
    .controller('ctrl2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Some data for view2';
});
```

View the demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/neridum/whLa8k6k/